# Remove JTable row without convert RowIndex To Model

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, tablemodel

I know that for remove a row i should do this:

```
        if (table.getSelectedRow() > -1) {
        int rowToTable = table.getSelectedRow();
        int rowToModel = table.convertRowIndexToModel(rowToTable);
        model.removeBook(rowToModel);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select A Row");
    }
```

But, Now i try this method without `rowToModel` variable and still remove correctly:

```
        if (table.getSelectedRow() > -1) {
        int rowToTable = table.getSelectedRow();
        model.removeBook(rowToTable);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select A Row");
    }
```

My `removeBook()` method:

```
    public void removeBook(int row) {
    Connection connection;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    String query = "Delete from BookTable where id=?";
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
        Object id = this.getValueAt(row, 0);
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setObject(1, id);

        if (preparedStatement.executeUpdate() == 1) {
            this.removeRow(row);
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Why both of this works?!
And which is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it works without conversion only if the table is neither sorted nor filtered - as your code can't know whether it is, it must convert the row index always. BTW, same for column index, as the user might have moved the column

Comment: Well, Should i convert the row index for my `add()` and `edit()` methods too?